# Unable to access UITabBarItem(s) inside UITabBar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uitabbaritem

I have a TabBarController that contains 5 TabBarItems, i want to have a control over those items so i create a new class that extends `UITabBarController` and make it the delegate for the TabBarController `<UITabBarControllerDelegate>` then i bind the TabBarController on the story board with this class, but I'm unable to create any outlet for any UITabBarItem also i tried to print the titles of each TabBarItem in the viewWillAppear method as follows:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    UITabBarItem *tabItem=[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"Title:-------->%@",[tabItem title]);
}

}
```

but it prints Null foreach item title, what can i do to have a control over those TabBarItems ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you are accessing the `UITabBar`.

As you said, you already have this code placed in the class that is inherited from `UITabBarController`, then you should access the `UITabBar` as

```
self.tabBar
```

instead of

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar
```

Try using this efficient code:

```
for(UITabBarItem *item in [self.tabBar items]) {
    NSLog(@"Title: %@", [item title]);
}
```

Here is the attached sample project.[Project attached](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/problem-arc/tabBarItem.zip)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
    {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Favorites", @"Favorites");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first"];
    }
    return self;
}
```